# Misplaced and produced by a for loop

Tags: python-3.x

Totally new to programming. Working on the comma code example in Automate the boring stuff. The following code works (with some extra spaces I have to clean up). But on initialization, it prints the list correctly as in "The list is apples, bananas, tofu, **and** cats.
When you create a new list it does this instead: "The list is **and**, a, b, c, d."

```py
# initializing list   
test_list = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats'] 

# printing original list
while True:
    print('The list is ', end='')
    for i in range(0, len(test_list)):
        if i != (len(test_list)-1):
            print(str(test_list[i]), ', ', end='')
        if i == (len(test_list)-1):
            print('and', str(test_list[i]), '.')
    print('Write a new list that contains elements separated by a comma then space.')
    test_list = [input()]
```

Comment: Remove `continue`, it does not belong here (but it does not cause the problem). Also, remove all `str()`s.

Comment: I made the changes, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is the input is taking the full string and adding it as a single element to the `test_list` list. The string needs to be split.
The only thing that needs to be changed is the last line:

```
test_list = input().split(", ")
```

`>>>test1, test2, test3
The list is test1 , test2 , and test3 .`

As for cleaning up the extra spaces--concatenate the strings with `+` instead of `,`.

Combining all code:

```
# initializing list   
test_list = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats'] 

# printing original list
while True:
    print('The list is ', end='')
    for i in range(0, len(test_list)):
        if i != (len(test_list)-1):
            print(str(test_list[i]) + ', ', end='')
        if i == (len(test_list)-1):
            print('and', str(test_list[i]) + '.')
    print('Write a new list that contains elements separated by a comma then space.')
    test_list = input().split(", ")
```

Results in the output: `The list is test1, test2, and test3.`

There are several other things I would write differently, but this should solve your problem. Take care!

Comment: Thank You. I had not been exposed to the split command as of yet. I know the code is ugly, but it's a start:). Thank you again, this got it working correctly and I didn't have to have the user add a space to the comma-separated list.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't completed the exercises in Automate the Boring Stuff, though they look very useful, so I'm not completely sure what you've learned to this point. There is likely a way of achieving this same functionality with what you've already learned. Overall, your code isn't ugly--you're doing a great job! One thing you can eliminate is "str()" from each of your print commands. "Input" automatically reads the input in as a string unless you change the type. Keep it up! :)

Comment: Also, the split command splits a string based on what you've input (in the example above, we split the string every time it sees a comma). It then automatically adds each of the split portions into a list (which you assigned to "test_list" in the example. You can read more here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split